# How do I add a function to a collection?

Tags: c#

I have a class that manages keyboard input and fires off *KeyPressed*, *KeyReleased*, or *KeyHeld* events. It only fires off an event if the key exists in the KeyBindings collection of my Controller component. Now that I've got all of that working I'm stuck on a problem. What I want is the following:

```
Key pressed.

if(Key bind exists)
    Fire key pressed event.

foreach(function in keyBinds)
{
    execute function, fire event, whatever...
}
```

I just can't figure out how the foreach loop would work. Any ideas on how I could pull something like this off?

---

**KeyboardController Component:**

```
public class KeyboardController : IComponent
{
    //Fields
    private Dictionary<Keys, HashSet<Delegate>> m_keyBindings = new Dictionary<Keys,HashSet<Delegate>>();

    //Properties
    public Dictionary<Keys, HashSet<Delegate>> KeyBindings
    {
        get { return m_keyBindings; }
    }
}
```

This is the class that will contain the Keys and their function/delegate/event/whatever bindings. The code for events CANNOT be contained within this class because the class is meant only to store data. I need to pass a Key bind and an action or set of actions to perform when this bind is pressed.

**Adding a bind:**

```
//Set key bindings
KeyboardController kbController = entityManager.GetComponent<KeyboardController>(1);
kbController.KeyBindings.Add(Keys.Up, new HashSet<Delegate>());
kbController.KeyBindings[Keys.Up].Add(function);
```

I don't know how to make the third line in "Adding a bind:" work.

Comment: Are you just looking for the built-in event feature in C#?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8627sbea.aspx

Comment: No, I'm looking for the specific functionality of having a collection of functions/events/whatever to execute/fire when a particular KeyPress event is fired. I want to be able to "tack on" events pretty much at will.

Comment: I see.  I'm adding an answer with another possible solution now.

Comment: Added further details to help explain my need more accurately.

Comment: Any reason that you are using `System.Delegate` instead of a more specialized (and readable) delegate type like `Func` or `Action`, or even your own delegate type?

Comment: Honestly, no. I was just using Systam.Delegate as an example because I don't really know how I'm supposed to accomplish this. What I'm working on is WAYYY out of my league but doing is the only way to truly learn things.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [multicast delegate](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173175%28v=vs.80%29.aspx) to automatically fire off multiple events for a given key, this way you don't need to maintain a collection of events. For example:

```
Dictionary<Key, Action> bindings = ...
Action binding;
if (binding.TryGetValue(key, out binding))
  binding(); // this will execute multiple events if they are hooked
```

Hooking events:

```
bindings[Keys.A] += new Action(MyAKeyHandler);
```

If for some reason you didn't want to use multicast delegates, you could do something like this:

```
List<Action> handlers = binding[key];
...
if (handlers != null)
  foreach (var handler in handlers)
    handler();
```

Rather than HashSet use an actual delegate type such as Action<>.  For instance:

```
Dictionary<Keys, Action> handlers = ...
handlers[key] += function;
```

Comment: Ok, this sounds like where I want to go. Now, here's something I forgot to mention: the event to be fired/function to be executed up the key press CANNOT be defined in the Controller component. How does that change how I'd code this?

Comment: One option is to expose functions like AddKeyHandler(Key key, Action handler).  I'm wondering, however, if the Command pattern isn't more what you're looking for though?

Comment: It might be, I added some more details up top to give you a clearer picture of what I'm trying to do.

Comment: Okay, I added an example to the end of my answer.  Basically use KeyBindings[Keys.KeyUp] += function;

Comment: After a lot of messing around I think I finally understand this and have been able to bind multiple methods to a key successfully so I'm accepting your answer. However, I'd really appreciate it if you could help me a bit further with this. I would like individual key presses to be events themselves rather than just a generic "KeyPressed" event. Any thoughts on how I could do this elegantly?

Comment: Not sure what you're after exactly.  The above allows you to have separate handlers declared anywhere, then registered centrally with the  controller.  Think if it as handling the central event and distributing  individual specific key-strokes to whomever cares to listen.

Answer (score 2):

Since C# has delegate types as first-class language objects, you can just keep a collection of functions quite directly

```
var keyBinds = new List<Action<KeyPressEventArgs>>();

KeyPressEventArgs args = /* Something from the actual keypress event */;

foreach (Action<KeyPressEventArgs> function in keyBinds)
{
    function(args);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You may use collection of Delegates for this purpose. Check this link: http://xenta.codeplex.com/SourceControl/changeset/view/068ddfd6bf36#trunk%2fSrc%2fFwk%2fXenta.EventBroker.Default%2fBroker.cs. It's an event broker, where we use lists of delegates.